# Compare multiple values with SPARQL (recipe ingredients)

Tags: sparql, rdf, triplestore

We have a quite big amount of medieval recipes and their structured data stored as RDF in a triple store (Blazegraph). The ingredients are Wikidata items and each recipe is part of a recipe collection:

```
<https://example.com/b2.1> schema:recipeIngredient <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q10987>,
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q15046077>,
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q15622897>,
    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q42527>.
<https://example.com/b2.1> ex:isPartOfCollection <https://example.com/b2>.
```

Now I would like to query for recipes with the exact same ingredients and get the amount of recipes in each collection that are intersecting (i.e. which have the exact same ingredients) and the amount of recipes that are unique (i.e. no recipes with the same ingredients found in any other collection). I did this quite expensive query:

```
prefix corema: <https://gams.uni-graz.at/o:corema.ontology#>
prefix schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT (?coll as ?collectionURI) (count(distinct ?r2) as ?NoOfrecipesWithExcatSameIngredients) (group_concat(?r1;separator=", ") as ?UriOfrecipesWithExcatSameIngredients)
WHERE {
    {
        SELECT (group_concat(?ing1;
                separator=", ") as ?ingr1) ?r1 WHERE 
        {
            ?r1 a schema:Recipe;
                schema:recipeIngredient ?ing1.
        }
        GROUP BY ?r1
        ORDER BY ?r1
    }
    {
        SELECT (group_concat(?ing2;
                separator=", ") as ?ingr2) ?r2 ?coll WHERE 
        {
            ?r2 a schema:Recipe;
                schema:recipeIngredient ?ing2;
                corema:isPartOfCollection ?coll.
        }
        GROUP BY ?r2 ?coll
        ORDER BY ?r2
    }
    FILTER(?ingr1=?ingr2)
    FILTER(?r1!=?r2)
}
GROUP BY ?coll
ORDER BY ?collectionURI
LIMIT 10000
```

It works but 1) I don't know how to get the unique recipes and 2) the problem of unsecure ordering in group_concat (graphDB seems to stay stable while Blazegraphs gives me different numbers every time I run the query)

The output should be (as an example):

| Collection | Amount of intersecting recipes | Amount of unique recipes | Intersecting with (Uris of recipes) | Unique recipe URIS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b2 | 12 | 4 | ex:b4.2, ex:b5.6, ex:gr1.7 | ex:b2.2, ex:b2.6, ex:b2.1 |

Any help appreciated!

Comment: there is one limitation in SPARQL: the `group_concat` function has no concept of ordering, so the generated string could be `"i1, i2"` and `"i2, i1"`, thus, would be different. Even if you use `ORDER BY` in both subqueries, there is literally no guarantee - you might get lucky depending on the triple store and their implementation though

Comment: You said, "it works", but what do you get as result?

Comment: Performance is indeed bad, the query does cartesian product which might be expensive. But, you could use the Blazegraph feature of [named subqueries](https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/NamedSubquery), this might avoid to compute the same subquery twice.

Comment: I updated the query. The performance issue is gone now. But it is indeed a very big problem that group_concat cannot be ordered:/ As a result I currently get the collection, then the number of recipes that are (supposedly) the same and the recipes URIs that are supposed to be the ones with the same ingredients.